# jPlayer 2.0 iPhone/mobiles problem

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-ui, html, jplayer

i am using a jPlayer 2.0 in my site.
I detect mobile users.

Based on that:

1. I re-direct them to another link.
2. Since auto play doesnt start i ask them to press play.
3. After that the same button turns to a mute/unmute button (the volueme changes 0/100);

Here is the function. Notice the mobile = 1 part.
mobile = 1 variable is set when its a mobile (from my backend)

It all works fine except for the mute/unmute in mobiles.

```
 function pauseOrPlay()
 {
     if(mobile == 1 && MOBILE_PLAY == 0)
     {
//       alert("s");
         $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('play');
         MOBILE_PLAY = 1;
         $("#message").text("playing... enjoy the music");
         $("#message").fadeTo(2000,.3);
         $("#message").slideUp(2000);
         return;
     }
     if(playing == 1)
     {
         if(mobile == 1)
         {
             $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer("volume", 0);
         }
         else
         {
            $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('mute');
         }
         playing = 0;
     }
     else
     {
         if(mobile == 1)
         {
             $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer("volume", 1);
         }
         else
         {
            $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('unmute');
         }
         playing = 1;
     }
 }
```

Here is the link
Original (before redirecting based on mobile/pc) [player](http://bedupako.com/eradio.php)
Just the link for mobiles - [here](http://bedupako.com/liveradio.php?mobile=true)

My question: why does it not work only in phones

Does iPhone doesnt support volume support

Comment: You should do touch device detection on the client side. 
`var is_touch_device = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement)?true:false;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put the same question in jPlayer's official groups page. and got the answer as follows:

> Mobile browsers do not allow us to
>   change the volume nor muted values of
>   the media element. This is by their
>   browser design and there is nothing we
>   can do about it at this time. They
>   expect you to use their physical
>   volume buttons on the device to
>   control the volume.
>
> All you could do is browser sniff for
>   the mobile browser and hide those
>   controls since they do nothing.

So problem is not with script but with the browser in phone which prevents me from changing the volume,

Comment: I also found this to be a problem. Android behaves poorly when you try to set the volume. Once I removed code changing the volume for touch devices, the problem was fixed.